# Catagorizing items in ng-repeat based on index

Tags: angularjs, loops, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list of items say `items = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8, ...  ,40]`.
I am displaying these items using ng-repeat.

challenge is to display them in different divs based on the row count per column.
It should be displayed as

```
1 4 7

2 5 8

3 6 9
```

And so on. (if the row count is 3)

==============

```
1  5  9

2  6  10

3  7  11

4  8  12
```

And so on (if the row count is 4).
Each column should be in a separate div

## for example:

data is

```
scope. allItems = 
[{value = "apple" , id = 1},
{value = "mango" , id = 2},
{value = "banana" , id = 3},
{value = "grapes" , id = 4}]
```

so on till id = 40

and i am looping using ng-repeat

now all the fruits are coming in single div

apple

mango

banana

grapes

but i want it to be divided into 5 fruits per division
first 5 fruits in one div and another 5 in another div and os on.

Comment: Please give an example of the data you want to display, otherwise it is very difficult to understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: can do this using `css columns` in modern browsers that support it. Question is really lacking in details. Create a demo showing expected markup

Answer (score 0):

You can create a filter to reorder the items in columns.

http://jsbin.com/vinohusoba/edit?html,js,output

```
  <span ng-repeat="item in items | columns:3">
    {{item}}
    <br ng-if="($index+1) % 3 === 0"/>
  </span>
```

Filter:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
});

app.filter('columns', function() {
   return function(items, colCount) {
      var returnItems = [];

      var rows = Math.ceil(items.length / colCount);
      var cols = [];
      var currentCol = [];
      for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
         currentCol.push(items[i]);

         if((i+1)%rows === 0) {
            cols.push(currentCol);
            currentCol = [];
         }
      }

      for(var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
         for(var k = 0; k < colCount; k++) {
            returnItems.push(cols[k][i]);
         }
      } 

      return returnItems;
   };
});
```

How to style this- you'l have to figure that one out.

Comment: Hi @micah williamson,Thanks for your answer!
It is working fine. But i wanted each coloumn in a div. 
Our code is just dividing the li s with a break.

Comment: Per me comment - "How to style this- you'l have to figure that one out".